# unmappable character for encoding ASCII

Tags: java

What is the error  `error: unmappable character for encoding ASCII`. The code is:

```
outputWord = newWord + "ag’ ,r";
```

Comment: The character `’` is not supported in ASCII. Try `'` instead.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it and it works now.

Comment: (for your reference) the unicode escape sequence for your original char is "\u2019".

Answer (score 1):

Your ’ character is not supported by ASCII. If you need just an apostrophe, use `'` instead. If you need that character, you can use the Unicode escape code for it, for example `\u00a9` is the copyright symbol. You'll have to find the correct Unicode code for that special character.